# Converting an existing module to dynamic module caused data loss, after update looks like fresh installed app with no data, lost all the datas

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic-delivery

My Android app have 5 modules previously,
I converted one of them to dynamic module and pushed new aab to playstore (version code = n).
So now my app have 4 normal module and 1 dynamic module but the issue is, after updating to this app version the app datas are all cleared (shared preferences). It seems like a fresh install.
When a user with app version code < n loss all their data after updating to version n.

Cross checked with goolge documentation, but still have the issue